# How do I add an exponential curve to a categorical histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, curve-fitting

I have the following dataset:

```
Type <- c("Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 3", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 3", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 3", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1")
Group <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP")
Abundance <- c(79, 76, 66, 58, 51, 36, 35, 29, 26, 25, 24, 21, 9, 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Abundance_data <- data.frame (Type, Group, Abundance)
```

And I have made a barplot of abundance against group using this code:

```
# Create a vector to specify the colour and shape for each type
colours_by_type <- c("Type 1"="orange", "Type 2"="chartreuse4", "Type 3"="brown2")

# Reorder the data so that it goes from largest to smallest
Abundance_data_reordered <- transform (Abundance_data, Group = reorder(Group, order(Abundance, decreasing=TRUE))) # The data here is ordered already but my real data is not

# Create an ordered barplot
abundance_plot <- ggplot(data=Abundance_data_reordered, aes(x=Group, y=Abundance)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Type))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5))+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours_by_type)+ 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())+ 
  labs(y="Abundance")+ # 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

abundance_plot
```

This made the following plot:

[image]

I want to add a curve to this. I think an exponential curve would be the best fit but I can't work out how to do it as all the examples I've seen have numerical data on the x-axis.

Is there a way I can fit a regression curve or an exponential curve to my plot?

Comment: What do you want to fit a line? Unless `"A"`  to `"AP"` has some meaning as discrete or continuous data, I do not think you can give meaningful information. Maybe `"B = A + constant"`, and `"C = B + constant"` so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to regress against rank, it's quite straightforward:

```
df <- cbind(Abundance_data_reordered, index = 1:nrow(Abundance_data_reordered))
fit <- lm(log(Abundance) ~ index, data = df)
abundance_plot + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) exp(fit$coefficients[1] + x*fit$coefficients[2]))
```

[image]

Note that the line looks a bit off but it is the correct exponential fit for your data.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you!

Do you know if it's possible to calculate the R^2 for the curve?

Comment: You can use `summary(fit)`